# Javascript how to get list is on click on inner span

Tags: javascript

```
<li id="123">
  <span id="tst">test</span>
</li>
```

I have the above code. I would like to get the **li** id on click on **span** id. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What's this go to to with PHP? If anything this is JavaScript related.

Comment: Yes, possible on JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I meant with JavaScript @Eddie

Comment: Aside from also fixing the tags on your question, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Most easily to do with jQuery:

```js
$('span').click(function() {
  var parentId = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
  console.log(parentId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="123">
  <span id="tst">test</span>
</li>
```

Or as plain vanilla js:

```js
document.getElementById('tst').onclick = function() {
  var parentId = this.parentElement.id;
  console.log(parentId);
};
```

```html
<li id="123">
  <span id="tst">test</span>
</li>
```